# Database connection lost after some time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I have developed one web application, in this JSF is front end and mysql is backend. Am using Hibernate ORM framework to connect the database. I host my application in tomcat which works fine for some hours of time. After some time i got some exception like,

```
Dec 25, 2014 9:50:50 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Dec 25, 2014 9:50:50 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
```

after that am not able to retrieve the value from database. If i restart my tomcat means it works fine for some hours of time.

```
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.253:3306/Test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">900</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
```

Any one suggest me the correct way to solve my error.

Answer (score 3):

probably connection closed by timeout. u can use validation query try something like this:

```
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period”>14400</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.timeout”>25200</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.max_size”>15</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.min_size”>3</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.max_statements”>0</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery”>select 1;</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with tomcat configuration pool and mysql.

You can verify the connection timeout of mysql db, via command:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.wait_timeout, @@global.interactive_timeout, @@session.wait_timeout, @@session.interactive_timeout;
```

Default value is 28800 seconds = 8 hours for mysql close connections unused. It's possible change this values in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = xxx
interactive_timeout = xxx
```

The best way to solve this problem in my case was change configuration pool parameters in tomcat (/etc/tomcat7/context.xml) no changes in my.cnf and without configuration c3p0 in app.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/yourxxxbd"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
initialSize="15"
maxActive="30"
maxIdle="15"
minIdle="15"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="28700"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="28750"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
validationInterval="28760"
testOnBorrow="true"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
username="youruser"
password="yourpass"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourxxxbd?allowMultiQueries=true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.253:3306/Test?autoReconnect=true</property>
```

As addition, I have had same issue with c3p0, so i swithced to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource like:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="false" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
    </bean>
```